# What is the elegant technique/method that will extract the "AA" string from the "simple{AA}" expression?

Tags: java-8, apache-camel

***Using this example, below:*** the expression body().toString() yields "simple{AA}"...
But, I really only want the "AA" value...

-how do I extract the string (in this case: "AA") from the "simple{}"  expression?...

```
    from("timer://foo?fixedRate=true&period=" + 5000) //5 seconds... 
            .setBody(constant(s))            
            .to("direct:thingB");

    from("direct:thingB")
        .setBody(constant("AA,BB")) 
            .split().tokenize(",")
            .to("direct:thingC");       

    from("direct:thingC")
            .log("body=" + body());   <== I want the "AA" without the "simple{}" part....
```

***QUESTION:***  What is the elegant technique/method that will extract the "AA" string from the "simple{AA}" expression?

Comment: please don't add the answer to the question body. I have rolled back your edit. If you found a solution you are encouraged you add an answer to your own post.

Comment: answer posted. thx!  :-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer I was looking for is to use the following expression:

.log("body=" + "${body}");

Comment: You can find more of these in the Simple documentation on the Camel website.

Answer (score 0):

Simply use a [Processor](https://camel.apache.org/processor.html) bean.

Define a bean

```
<bean id="extractData" class="com.my.package.ExtractData" />
```

Use it your route:

```
from("direct:thingC")
        .log("body=" + body())
        .to("bean:extractData")
        .log("body=" + body());
```

Write your DRY and [SRP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Single_responsibility_principle) code

```
public class ExtractData implements Processor {

    @Override
    public void process(Exchange exchange) throws Exception {
        String body = exchange.getIn().getBody(String.class);
        String whatYouWant = applySomeRegexpOrStringSplit(body);
        exchange.getIn().setBody(whatYouWant);
    }

    private String applySomeRegexpOrStringSplit(String input) { ... }
}
```